# Enable Federated engine in MySQL 5.6 Windows

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, federated

I am trying to enable Federated engine in MySQL. I did followed some post and blogs and i edited my-default.ini [Location: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6] by adding federated keyword under [mysqld].

```
[mysqld]
federated
```

Later i have restarted MySQL Server and i went to cross verify whether it is enabled or not by firing SQL Query show engines;

```
Engine            Support            Transactions          XA     Savepoints
FEDERATED           NO                    NULL            NULL       NULL
```

Can any one please help me.

Environment 
Operating System : Windows 7 64bit
MySQL Version : 5.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct edit, wrong file location.

The location for the configuration file for MySQL v5.6 with a default MySQL Installer installation on Windows 7 64-bit is:

C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini

Not C:\Program Files..

Answer (score 2):

Excelent!

I have tried this and it works fine.

Open a Windows Explorer and type 'C:\ProgramData' then enter the MySQL folder and you'll see the my.ini file.

Just ad federated unde [mysqld]

And that's all.

Also you can go to Tools on the windows explorer and select Folder Options, then View tab, and activate the 'Show hidden files and folder' option.

Now you'll be able to see the ProgramData filer.

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 2):

Just for the info of wamp users:

> Edit my.ini @ C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17

Navigate at end of file where you find [mysqld] and then append/add federated keyword at end.

```
[mysqld]
port=3306
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = TRUE
federated
```

Once done verify on wamp phpmyadmin console

[image]